Why did early pulps make use of “house names” where multiple authors wrote under the same pseudonym?
In his January 1984 Editorial in Asimov’s, the eponymous editorial director asks

The early pulps occasionally made use of
"house names.” A particular magazine would use a pseudonym that was
never used except in that magazine, but that pseudonym might be used
by any number of different writers. I have never really understood why
this was done and if any reader knows I would appreciate being told.

This seems like a significant question of sf history, and I am surprised there isn’t a ready internet answer, forty years after it was posed by the Good Doctor. Is there historical evidence as to why such a practice was used?

Maybe it was just easier to reuse the same house names instead of inventing new ones for every issue? I wonder how many readers even paid attention to the authors' names? I'm pretty sure I didn't whan I was reading those pulps back in the 1940s.

If you don't have any recognisable names, than make one! It also looks like a brand of a product, which they were.

There is also the reason to "Hide" the name of the real author. Those who might not want it known they are writing in that genre. Or only wrote in a genre for a paycheck, while working on their slowly progressing "Next Novel". The "adult sleaze" pulp books of the 50s, 60s & 70s? are a perfect example. MANY well known authors wrote books in this genre and used "house" names to hide there involvement, not wanting the public to know they were writing what was essential at the time porn novels (although quite tame by todays standards).

I think the answer is simply that the house name gives the impression that the quality of all the stories in any particular issue will be the same as the quality of the stories in any other issue. Pulps were sold as a commodity ("Contains an entire short novel!" "160 pages of thrills," etc.), so anything that suggested variability (like different authors this month) was perceived as a negative. It's also likely that publishing houses wished to make authors disposable - and the way to do that is to make sure that if "Joe Smith" (writing under the house name of "Richard Hardjaw") demanded a raise or became otherwise a problem, "John Doe" could slip into the job of being "Richard Hardjaw" without the customers having a moment of doubt.
This article on the subject confirms the second reason:

In the pulps, I’m not sure when they started to be used, but the first
I knew of its use is with “Maxwell Grant” as the author of The Shadow,
rather than credit Walter B. Gibson. Interestingly, Gibson created
that name, using the names of two magic dealers. When you keep in mind
that The Shadow, like the previous dime novel characters, was owned by
the publisher, this is why. This was different from the many previous
serialized characters that were owned by the authors, as well as you
now had a magazine focused on and named for the character.
Hence the main reason for the use of house names was that should there
need to be a new author to write the character, this can be hidden
under the house name, and so most, but certainly not all, of the
character pulps to follow did this. Making it more tricky is when
these house names would be used for other characters, or would be used
by the publisher for more wider use.

I should also note that house names were and are common in markets that appeal to the same folks expected to read the pulps - like "Franklin Dixon" for The Hardy Boys, "Carolyn Keane" for Nancy Drew and "Ellery Queen" for the Ellery Queen books.

Thank you for your prompt answer! ( I will accept and upvote when my new account allows). The practice seems shortsighted to modern eyes, since sophisticated readers would notice the differences in quality and style from ‘house names’ but, on the other hand, early pulp readers aged 10 might not have caught this!

For context, this is quite common in the music industry as well, for more or less the same reasons; Tina Turner is a prominent example since it was her 'personal' stage name but an awful lot of bands have changed their line-ups (sometimes entirely) and I'd say that's pretty much the same thing.

It still happens today. "Erin Hunter" of the Warrior Cats books is half a dozen different authors. They apparently chose the surname because it would get them put next to Brian Jacques's Redwall series in libraries and bookshops.

It's just branding and brand recognition. Professional writers can write in any style demanded of them, just as multiple cartoonists can contribute to The Simpsons without viewers being able to spot which artist supplied particular scenes.

Also, the books appear in the same place on bookshelves that are ordered by author (i.e. bookshop bookshelves!), so your entire series is in one place.

Richard Hardjaw is an amazing name. I can't believe this reply is the only instance of that name on the internent.

Glad you like it

@forty-year-old-question "quality" and "style" aren't necessarily words one attributes to pulps. Or at least wasn't what the publishers were going for. ("Available at most corner stores, for only one dollar!" was more the goal.)

@R.M. I'd take a Robert E Howard or HP Lovecraft any day over a Dan Brown.  Or Robert Jordan for that matter (no, I don't expect that to be a popular opinion).  And that's only going from high recognition authors, before you get into the morass of Mil SF authors writing cheapo kindles books at the rate of 5-6 a year.

@R.M. I agree that pulps were generally of low quality, but some of them were absolutely oozing with style, often to the exclusion of all else. Style is cheap. Quality is expensive.

@R.M. More like a dime or a quarter.

By the way @forty-year-old-question, please come back with more questions, even if they are only 35 years old
